# Pygame: Image/Sprite not appearing on moving background

Tags: python, background, pygame, character

The image I uploaded is not appearing onto the moving background. However, when the background was still it showed up normally (i was able to see the character and make it jump using the space key). Have been trying to figure out the error for days, please help - thank you!!!!
The following is the portion of code used for the character and moving background.

```
background = pygame.image.load('background.png')
backgroundX = 0
backgroundX2 = background.get_width()
homeScreen = pygame.image.load('home_screen.png')


def redrawGameWindow():
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    man.draw(screen)
    # background images for right to left moving screen
    screen.blit(background, (backgroundX, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (backgroundX2, 0))
    pygame.display.update()


# create class for character (object)
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):  # initialize attributes
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.left = True
        self.right = True
        self.isJump = False
        self.stepCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.standing = True

    def draw(self, screen):
        if self.stepCount + 1 >= 27:  # 9 sprites, with 3 frames - above 27 goes out of range
            self.stepCount = 0

        if not self.standing:
            if self.left:
                screen.blit(leftDirection[self.stepCount // 5], (self.x, self.y), man.pos)
                self.stepCount += 1
            elif self.right:
                screen.blit(rightDirection[self.stepCount // 5], (self.x, self.y), man.pos)
                self.stepCount += 1
        else:
            if self.right:
                screen.blit(rightDirection[0], (self.x, self.y))  # using index, include right faced photo
            else:
                screen.blit(leftDirection[0], (self.x, self.y))


class enlargement(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius, 1)


#  main loop

speed = 30  # NEW
man = player(200, 410, 64, 64)  # set main character attributes
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(speed)  # NEW
    backgroundX -= 1.4  # Move both background images back
    backgroundX2 -= 1.4

    if backgroundX < background.get_width() * -1:  # If our background is at the -width then reset its position
        backgroundX = background.get_width()

    if backgroundX2 < background.get_width() * -1:
        backgroundX2 = background.get_width()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False  # false, because man is walking
    # verify that character is within window parameters
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False  # false, because man is walking
    else:
        man.standing = True
        man.stepCount = 0

    if not man.isJump:
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            man.isJump = True  # when jumping, man shouldn't move directly left or right
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.stepCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg  # to jump use parabola
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your probably just redrawing the background last ,thus it covers your sprite every time, I've had the issue in Visual Studio's C# (the old MonoGame library). By the way that's just a guess without completely going over your code. Good luck!